# SSIS - Postgres to SQL Server (sql server agent job)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, odbc

I have created a SSIS sequence connecting to Postgres via ODBC 32bit - debugging this via Visual Studios all connects and works.

I deployed to SQL Server as an Integration Services Catalog and I can execute my 3 packages manually (marking the execute as 32bit runtime).

My problem now is when I create a Job via SQL Server agent and I define each step to execute as 32bit runtime, it complains about:

> ADO NET source has failed to acquire the connection: the specified
>   DSN contains architecture mismatch between the driver and application

I have trolled the net with everyone saying 'make sure 32bit runtime is checked', 'ensure that in Visual Studios you say false to run in 64bit mode' but feels like I have missed a trick somewhere and I am baffled.

If anyone has any insights please?

Visual Studios 2015
SQL Server 2016

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Answered one time this question, but I add 4 step. 
If I good see you didn't do the 2 step?

There several steps to run a SSIS package in 32 bits:

1. Check if ODBC is created in 32 bit. Real odbc 32 bit administrator is in folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
2. Check if SSIS package has cheked run64bitruntime property FALSE.
3. Check if SQL Agent property 'Use 32 bit runtime' checked.
4. Check if ODBC Created in ODBC Administrator in System DSN tab - Because if You create in User dsn tab just your user will see that odbc.

Comment: points 1, 2, 3 are as you defined already.
creating a System DSN now to see if that helps resolve issue.
thanks for the pointers tho Justin

Comment: Report back if this solve your problem. There maybe a couple of ODBC with same name in 32 bit and 64 bit administrator or sql agent service account doesn't have permissions to see ODBC...

Comment: Justin's System DSN ODBC connection worked for me. Much love x